# How can I dynamically adjust the height of a fixed-height table in Grafana dashboard using Puppeteer to display all rows without scrolling?

Tags: javascript, node.js, automation, puppeteer, grafana

I am using Puppeteer with Node.js to automate the export of a Grafana dashboard (Grafana version is Open Source v7.5.8). The dashboard contains a table with a fixed height of 197px. However, the table often has more rows than can be displayed within this fixed height, so need to scroll to see all the rows.

So how can I dynamically adjust the height of the table so that all rows are visible without the need for scrolling and I can export the entire table without losing any rows?

I would appreciate any guidance on how to accomplish this task. Thank you!